# Draw String not visible on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

So for my assignment I need to create a triangle object using this `public void draw(Graphics2D g)` method to render triangle shape on the canvas.

I tested it out to see if I can print out simple text onto my screen before I start going into the deeper part of my code. I am use to using `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and it works when I use that method. But it is blank when I use the `public void draw(Graphics2D g)` method.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Window window = new Window();
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      window.setSize(700,500);
      window.setLocation(400,100);
      window.setTitle("Draw Pad");
      window.initialize();
      window.setVisible(true);
     }
}

import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Window extends JFrame {
    public void initialize(){
    DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
    Container contentPane = getContentPane(); 
    contentPane.add("Center", panel);
    }
}

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    //Doesn't work using this
    public void draw(Graphics2D g)
    {
       g.drawString(("Hello"), 100, 100);
    } 
    //Works using this
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawString(("Hello"),100,100); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just get an empty window, also I didn't include the imports so I could take up less space. In case you just copied it.

Comment: I just get a bunch of compiler errors - how ever - ask yourself this question - how does your `draw` method get called?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't include the initialize method, now it is in there. Than I call that method from main.

Comment: *"Than I call that method from main."* - where do you get the `Graphics` context from to pass to the method? Instead, check the links in the answer to better understand how painting actually works, rather then trying to make guess at it

Comment: @MadProgrammer It automatically draws the graphics when I add it to contentPane. Then when I need to call it again, I just use contentPane.repaint(). Take a look, I added the paintComponent(Graphics g) and it works.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added everything that I have to the question. It should compile now.

Comment: *"I added the paintComponent(Graphics g) and it works"* - okay, and now you question is?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am required to use "public void draw(Graphics2D g)" method. I cannot draw a string using this but it works for paintComponent. Why doesn't it work for the other method?

Comment: Call `draw` from `paintComponent` - This is how painting works in Swing

Comment: Why do you expect `public void draw(Graphics2D g)` to do anything ? I don't see it invoked at all. Anyway Swing paint invokes `paint() invokes paintComponent()` and you should override it to add the functionality you want.

Comment: @c0der oh my goodness, your right. I didn't even catch that. It worked when I implemented it. Wish I could give you a green check mark. Message back if you know a way.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Posted as an answer. It would be wise to read the links @MadProgrammer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping over the issue of the code example not compiling; you need to start by having a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and
- [Painting in Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

to better understand how painting actually works and how you can work with it

I would then recommend that you go have a look at [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) to get a better understanding of how text is rendered using `Graphics2D`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect public void `draw(Graphics2D g)` to do anything ?
 I don't see it invoked at all.
 Anyway Swing paint invokes `paint()` invokes `paintComponent()` and you should override it to add the functionality you want.